# Haskell : force evaluation/avoid garbage collecting when composing functions

Tags: haskell

I was looking for an elegant way to write this code :

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

combi = [(x,y) | x <- [2..100], y <- [x..100]]

gsp = group (sort [x*y | (x,y) <- combi])
counts = zip (map head gsp) (map length gsp)

multipleProducts x = (fromJust (lookup x counts)) > 1
possibleComb1 = [(x,y) | (x,y) <- combi, multipleProducts (x*y)]
```

As I am reusing the same pattern multiple times but based on different input sets than `[x*y | (x,y) <- combi]`, I came out with this code.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

combi = [(x,y) | x <- [2..100], y <- [x..100]]

onlyOneEl e x = (fromJust (lookup x counts)) == 1
    where gs = group (sort e)
          counts = zip (map head gs) (map length gs)

multipleProducts = not.(onlyOneEl [x*y | (x,y) <- combi])
possibleComb1 = [(x,y) | (x,y) <- combi, multipleProducts (x*y)]
```

However, Haskell seems to compute `gs` and `count` for every single time I call multipleProducts, taking a very big amount of time, instead of computing it only once, since the value of e is always the same with multipleProducts.

What is the most elegant way of avoiding the recalculation ?
Is there anything better than pre-calculating `counts` using one function and storing it in a local variable, and then passing it to `onlyOneEl` without the where ?

Because I'm later reusing `onlyOneEl` based on different sets, and I wanted to avoid having multiple `counts` variables.

I understood [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where#Problems_with_where) why it did not evaluate it once per function, however, I do not use x as my last argument, and thus cannot do it exactly this way.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'd tend to write it as `onlyOneEl e = \ x -> ... where ...` and see if that helped.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled?

Comment: @LouisWasserman That looks indeed like the solution, but as I'm not an expert in Haskell, could you detail more ? :)
Having optimizations enabled doesn't change anything

Comment: From an elegance standpoint, `Data.List.group` is kind of a disgusting function. I would recommend using [Data.List.NonEmpty.group](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18.1/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#g:5) instead, since it prevents you from having to use a partial function (`Prelude.head`) to inspect the result. `Data.List.NonEmpty.head`, in contrast, is perfectly safe.

Comment: Also, `fromJust` shouldn't be used in real code.

Comment: @Ten it's simply that GHC is only able to inline functions where the left-hand side is fully-applied in the brain-dead syntactic sense. By doing that eta conversion GHC is likely moving the body of `onlyOneEl` into `multipleProducts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition

```
onlyOneEl e x = fromJust (lookup x counts) == 1
    where gs = group (sort e)
          counts = zip (map head gs) (map length gs)
```

says "given `e` and `x`, set up the computations of `gs` and `counts` and use their (lazily calculated) results to calculate the expression `fromJust (lookup x counts) == 1`. You could write it completely equivalently as

```
onlyOneEl e x =
  let gs = ...
      counts = ...
  in fromJust ...
```

On the other hand, if you move the `x` over to the other side with a lambda expression,

```
onlyOneEl e = \x -> fromJust ...
  where ...
```

then you pull `gs` and `counts` into an outer scope. This code is equivalent to

```
onlyOneEl e =
  let gs = ...
      counts = ...
  in \x -> fromJust ...
```

So `gs` and `counts` will only be calculated once per application of `onlyOneEl` to a single argument.

GHC supports a transformation called "full laziness" that does this kind of modification, which it applies when it thinks it will be a good idea. Apparently, GHC made the wrong judgement in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite it with little more goal oriented.  Without getting into math, just with generation of data and filtering you can achieve the same with much less computation.

When you generate the product, add the multipliers to the tuple as well, i.e.

```
combi n = [((x,y),x*y) | x<-[2..n], y<-[x..n]]
```

now you can sort and group based on product

```
multi = filter ((>1) . length) . groupBy ((==) `on` snd) . sortBy (comparing snd) . combi
```

and extract the first element of the tuple, which will be the (x,y) pair to give same product more than once.

```
map (map fst) (multi 100)
```

if you don't care about the grouping, you can flatten the result, i.e.

```
concatMap (map fst) (multi 100)
```